# How to watch all variables when debugging in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to watch all variables when debugging in Visual Studio 2012 like i can do it in IntelliJ Idea 12? I have a window with all the variables(both global and local) when debugging in Idea and i want the same thing in VS 2012 (Autos window is not enough) . Help is very much appreciated.
EDIT: All variables means variables that were already declared in code like:

```
Class Example
  Dim i as Integer
  Sub test()
   Dim a as String
   Dim b as Double
  End Sub
End Class
```

When I enter test() Autos window no longer displays i.

Comment: You should be able to see 'i' in Autos through the accessor **Me** (if I remember well in VB) the equivalent of **this** in C#.

Answer (score 43):

Many options:

1. **Autos**
   While debugging you can enable **'Autos'** which will show you values by every member on your class.
   Go to menu **Debug->Windows->Autos** to make it appear.
2. **Locals**
   While debugging you can enable **'Locals'** which will show you all variables in the current stack frame.
   Go to menu **Debug->Windows->Locals** to make it appear.
3. **Watch**
   Although it is a little manually you also can use **'Watch'** you can drag and drop any variable to this window or right click then **add to watch**.
   Go to menu **Debug->Windows->Watch** to make it appear. Note. You can enable more than one watch window :).
4. **Mouse over**
   Finally you can go over the variable with the mouse and you will see the variable's value.

Comment: Thanks, i prefer Autos and Mouse over :) But worth to try 'em all

Answer (score 0):

You can move your mouse on a variable and wait for 1 second until a "mini" window appears. What you can see it depends on the code block your breakpoint exist.

Also to display a variable window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx

Comment: This is good when you want to just to check the value. If you want to get the value of a variable better use Locals or something.

Answer (score 0):

you can select debug-> windows-> watch(click on it)  and it will appear in the below of visual studio where output window or others window show. You can type the variable name here like below to explore the objects or variable
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c1Hs.png)